# How to change visibility of a div css to visible with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have NEXT and PREVIOUS buttons on my screen. When the page initially loads I want the Previous button to be hidden and as soon as user clicks the Next button I want Previous button (div tag to be visible). I have a CSS property for Previous button where I am setting the visibility value to False. 
And also an if statement where I check to see if page counter is greater than 1 then change the visibility of navigationButtonTop to true. It is not working..what am I doing wrong !?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#navigationButtonTop").css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

```css
div.navigationButtonTop {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigationButtonTop"></div>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

firstly you have not closed your if statement and `navigationButtonTop` is a class not a id try this.

```
if (that.get("pageCounter") >= 1) {
     $(".navigationButtonTop").css("visibility", "visible");
}
```

as the OP has edited his question the new answer would be:

```
$(function() {
  $(".navigationButtonTop").css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Josh.. I should have used "." instead of #. This worked out for me ! :)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the code of how you actually like to trigger the event, would be nice to know. Maybe the trigger is not working at all?

Additionaly you addressed differently. In CSS `navigationButtonTop` is a class (see the ".") and in JS it's an id (see the "#"). Is this the culprit in your atual code? If not I'll assume it's an id further...

For more readability try to move your `visibility: hidden` to an extra hidden class. So you just can trigger:

```
$("#navigationButtonBottom").on('click', function() {
  $("#navigationButtonTop").removeClass('hidden');
});
```

And in you HTML add the class `hidden` to your button

```
#navigationButtonTop.hidden { visibility:hidden; }
```

Or do it using javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
  $("#navigationButtonTop").addClass('hidden');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In your JS you use ID ("#" sign before selector's name). But in your CSS you use CLASS (dot sign before selector's name).

Try to use "#" in both cases (or dot accordingly).

Answer (score 1):

Havde you tried $("#navigationButtonTop").show();

Comment: That is exactly what he did.

Comment: why would you answer a different way to what he has tried.. he has used the css binding so fix his problem dont suggest things which are just guessing.

Comment: I did change my comment straight away

Comment: @josh its not guessing. It is the recommended way to show a dom element in jquery

Comment: so is css binding you not solved his problem if you actually looked at why its not working its very easy.. your repeating different ways to do it.. if the css binding does not work why would you show binding work.. its just a waste of time to read

Comment: css binding is not the recommended way, but i agree with your comment of solving his original problem:)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Detect-DOM-Visibility-Change-jQuery-HideShow.html) a good *jQuery plugin* that saved me in a [*Materialize's collapsible*](https://materializecss.com/collapsible.html) customization, to avoid the use of a `click` event replaced with this `visibilityChanged` event.

In particular, the used code (among the various alternatives described in the plugin page) has been:

> HTML

```
<li id="collapsible_trigger">
    <div class="collapsible-header"></div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"></div>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="hideshow.min.js"></script>
```

> JS

```
$("#collapsible_trigger .collapsible-body").hideShow();
$("#collapsible_trigger .collapsible-body").on("visibilityChanged", function(event, visibility){
    /* your custom code here */
});
```