# Show/hide element based on dropdown selection value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown menu for selecting a filter for the frontpage content. I want it so that if the selected value is "top" a second dropdown appears next to it with the timeframes. I have the HTML and CSS for both of them, but can't get the JQuery working.

**What I tried to do with the JQuery is like the following:**

```
if (.order value == "top") {
    change .order-time to .order-time-display;
}
```

```css
.order-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.order-text {
  display: inline-block;
}

.order-menu {
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.order-container select {
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.order-container p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.order-container option {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.order-time {
  display: none;
}

.order-time-display {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="order-container">
  <div class="order-text">
    <p>Order:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="order-menu">
    <select name="order" class="order">
      <option value="hot" selected> Hot </option>
      <option value="recent"> Recent </option>
      <option value="top"> Top </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <select name="order-time" class="order-time">
    <option value="24h" selected> 24h </option>
    <option value="week"> Week </option>
    <option value="month"> Mont </option>
    <option value="year"> Year </option>
    <option value="all"> All </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take a look at this question/answer which is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434360/how-to-change-visibility-of-a-div-css-to-visible-with-jquery  or post actual code (not pseudo code) of what you have tried for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `change` event on the `.order` element.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".order").on("change", function() {
    if (this.value === "top") {
      $(".order-time").addClass("order-time-display")
    } else {
      $(".order-time").removeClass("order-time-display")
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.order-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.order-text {
  display: inline-block;
}

.order-menu {
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.order-container select {
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.order-container p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.order-container option {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.order-time {
  display: none;
}

.order-time-display {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="order-container">
  <div class="order-text">
    <p>Order:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="order-menu">
    <select name="order" class="order">
      <option value="hot" selected> Hot </option>
      <option value="recent"> Recent </option>
      <option value="top"> Top </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <select name="order-time" class="order-time">
    <option value="24h" selected> 24h </option>
    <option value="week"> Week </option>
    <option value="month"> Mont </option>
    <option value="year"> Year </option>
    <option value="all"> All </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to display the second select box `order-time` based on the first's value where the value should be `top` to display it ..

```js
$(document).on('change', 'select[name=order]', function () {

  let val = $(this).val();
  let orderTimeSelectBox = $('select[name=order-time]')

  if (val === 'top') {

    orderTimeSelectBox.show()
  }
  else {
    orderTimeSelectBox.hide()
  }
})
```